# Specific category url in osclass

Tags: url, osclass, user-friendly

I am using osclass3.1 in my site www.carsangrah.com. I have deleted all the categories except one (buy used car). I am able to get non user friendly url for this category i.e. http://www.carsangrah.com/index.php?page=search&sCategory=2. Please suggest me how to get used friendly url for this category.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('category', osc_get_category('id', $id)); //Optional if the category is already exported
echo osc_search_category_url() ;
```